# youtube-dl wrongly thinks it "finished downloading playlist"

Tags: youtube-dl

I tried to resume downloading a playlist with `youtube-dl`, but I get the message:

> finished downloading playlist

which isn't true. I've updated `youtube-dl`, and cleaned out the playlist as well as the target folder, but still get the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `-i` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading your playlist again with the `--no-continue` option. It will start over and download the entire playlist.